# iOS width of view not calculating correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, interface, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a view with a subview that is designed to show a user what fraction of games they have won and lost, like so:
[image: User profile screen]
The width of the green view is calculated by taking the width of the superview, multiplying it by the fraction of games won (which in this case is .5), and changing the width constraint of the green view to the calculated value.

```
let percent = Float(won)/Float(self.partiesPlayed)  //percent of games won, should be .5
let width = CGFloat(percent) * self.winLoseView.bounds.size.width  //multiply width of superview by percent

self.greenWidthConstraint.constant = CGFloat(width)  //change constraint's constant
UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {  // animate change
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

[image]

The problem is that the width does not appear to be exactly correct, for instance in this example it doesn't appear to be exactly half of the superview.

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes I am.  Instead of changing the view's width, I'm changing its width constraint and reloading constraints.

Comment: Based on your description ("doesn't appear to be exactly correct")... 

Silly question time: Have you confirmed via NSLog and/or debugger whether this is a data issue (green width is being set incorrectly) or a constraint/layout issue (the value is being set properly but the resultant layout system isn't what you expect)?

Comment: ok, the green/red view are totally the width of superview? did you calculate the padding left and right?

Comment: The superview is a red rectangle, with a green rectangle as the subview.

Comment: And to @BradBrighton it appears that the width is being set correctly: using NSLog shows that the green width is 152 and the total width is 304

Comment: What do you get when logging the actual frame widths following `layoutIfNeeded`? Also: "for instance in this example it doesn't appear to be exactly half of the superview"; which example? What are you referring to?

Comment: There are 8 wins and 8 losses, so the green bar should be .5 the width of the superview.  But in the screenshot, it doesn't appear to be half of the superview, confirmed by using a measurement utility.

Comment: And also @Tommy after the change it logs the same, 152 and 304

Comment: What other constraints do you have applied?

Comment: Also the width of the green bar within your image *is* 152 points. The width of that whole area is around 288 points. The problem would therefore appear to be that you're doing the wrong calculation, not that the size you set is being ignored.

Comment: For the superview, view to leading is 0, trailing to view is 0, height=32. For the green, superview to leading is 0, temporary width is 0 (removed at run)

Comment: Should I be getting the width of the bar some different way?

Comment: Is `winLoseView` definitely wired to the correct thing? If you log its `subviews` do you see the right sort of thing? If you have an outlet to the green bar and you log its `superview`, do you get the `winLoseView`?

Comment: @Tommy I NSLoged winLoseView and it appears to be wired to the right view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68109/discussion-between-milesper-and-tommy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach: Why not just remove the `greenWidthConstraint`and re-apply it with a constraint equal to the width of the red view and set the multiplier to the percentage won. That way, if you supported rotation or any other size change, you wouldn't worry about a fixed width value constant. I'm not up to par w/ swift yet, but here's it in Objective-c:

```
[self.view removeConstraint:self.constraint];
self.constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.greenView
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                  toItem:self.redView
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                              multiplier:PERCENTAGE
                                                constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:self.constraint];

// Animate the layoutIfNeeded....
```

Here's Swift version: (provided by @milesper)

```
let percent = Float(won)/Float(self.partiesPlayed)
var constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.greenSection, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.winLoseView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: CGFloat(percent), constant: 0.0 as CGFloat)
self.view.addConstraint(constraint)
UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  I'm just going to translate it into Swift